# Pendulum-like odeint integration

Tags: python, integration, numerical, odeint

I'm trying to solve a pendulum-like differential equation that goes like `d2(phi)/dt = -(g/R) *sin(phi)` (it's the skateboard problem in Taylor's Classical Mechanics). I'm new to scipy and odeint and the like, so I'm doing this to prepare for more sophisticated numerical solutions in the future.

I've used code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070437/pendulum-simulation-in-python-using-odeint-not-quite-working-as-a-pendulum) to try and navigate the coding, but all I'm coming up with is a flat line for `phi(t)`. I think it stems from the fact that I'm trying to split a second order differential equation into two first orders, where one doesn't depend on the other (because d(phi)/dt  to make an appearance); but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

Anyone know what's wrong with it?

```
    # integrate skateboard problem, plot result
    from numpy import *
    from scipy.integrate import odeint 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def skate(y, t, params):
        phi, omega = y
        g, R = params
        derivs = [omega, -(g/R)*np.sin(phi)]
        return derivs

   # Parameters
   g = 9.81
   R = 5
   params = [g, R]

   #Initial values
   phi0 = 20
   omega0 = 0
   y0 = [phi0, omega0]

   t = linspace(0, 20, 5000)

   solution = odeint(skate, y0, t, args=(params,))

   plt.plot(t, solution[:,0])
   plt.xlabel('time [s]')
   plt.ylabel('angle [rad]')
   plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a bug here: -(g/R)***np**.sin(phi). Perhaps you forget to define the alias for numpy lib import (for example: import numpy as np). Instead you just did (from numpy import *). Try this:

```
def skate(y, t, params):
    phi, omega = y
    g, R = params
    derivs = [omega, -(g/R)*sin(phi)]
    return derivs
```